# How to remove recovery/default email addresss

Tags: security, yahoo-mail

Someone has been trying to access my Yahoo Mail account through password recovery. I changed the password, so this is no longer a problem, but as I was going through "I forgot my password" recovery steps to see what this person saw, I was shocked to see my other email address fully listed. This is very troublesome because it states my full name. I went through the steps to add another default email address, but when I went through the recovery steps again, the old email address is still listed. I don't know how I'm supposed to remove this. I went through options and I still can’t get rid of it.

Answer (score -1):

I can't remove the email adress of around the same age. I've found another user with the same problem https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/how-to-remove-recovery-email-from-yahoo-mail/.

It looks like the only options left are support or delete the account.